# Order By Datetime in SQL Server not ordering Properly

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to Order my dataset By Datetime in SQL Server. Using `dd/mm/yyyy` format. You can assume following query for simplicity.

```
Select CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), DateColumn, 103) from myTable order by DateColumn DESC;
```

But it returns records only sorted by `dd and ignores mm,yy.`You can have a look over following data.

```
29/07/2015
26/09/2015
25/09/2015
25/09/2015
24/07/2015
22/09/2015
12/06/2015
01/10/2015
```

What should i do so that it may also include `mm and yy` as well while ordering.

Comment: Column DateColumn's data type?

Comment: What data type does `DateColumn` have in the database?

Comment: Yes DataType is DateTime

Comment: And, based on Gordon Linoff's answer, does the query in your question produce the results in your question, or did you modify the query before including it in your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that your actual query is:

```
Select CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), DateColumn, 103) as DateColumn
-------------------------------------------------^ Note alias here is the same as used in the order by
from myTable
order by DateColumn DESC;
```

The `order by` then uses the column definition in the select.  You can change the name.  Alternatively, use a qualified column name in the `order by`:

```
Select CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), t.DateColumn, 103) as DateColumn
from myTable t
order by t.DateColumn DESC;
```